# React JS include header

Tags: javascript, php, html, reactjs

So I'm new to React JS and currently I need some information about how to include HTML from another file to current file. For example in PHP I would have an index.php file and a header.php file.

In header.php file I would write a html code for my page's header, and then this header would be included in index.php by doing: `<?php include 'header.php'; ?>`

How can I do the same with React JS?

Having a component with `<Header /><Body />` just doesn't look ok to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You dont have HTML in ReactJS, what you have is HTML-like syntax called JSX.
2. You can include a React component into another component in a few different ways:

`import Header from 'Header'`

`import * as Header from './Header'`

`import {abc} from './Header'`

`require('Header')` also works.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I wanted. Oh yeah I meant JSX.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 different way to import another file in your file

1. import Header from 'Header'
2. import * as Header from './Header'
3. import {abc} from './Header'

there is one more method to import

require('Header')

but this is not used in updated version of reactjs so avoid using this method.

In react js you are not importing file you just import the component of that file.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to import the header file
 `import Header from 'Header'`or `var Header = require('Header')`